# MYSQL/PHP scandinavian letters

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a PHP file that gets data from mysql table and then json encodes it. Everything works fine until there is a row in mysql that has scandinavian letters. Then it only returns null

```
  {"key":[{"Name":null}]}
```

How can i make it work? Is the problem in PHP or in MYSQL? I tried to put `header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');` to the beginning of the php file, but that didn't work

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');
include 'config.php';


$sql = "Select * from table;



try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);  
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $dbh = null;
    echo '{"key":'. json_encode($results) .'}'; 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}


?>
```

When I use this code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","adsasd","asdasd");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("table", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT NAME from table where ID=1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['TABLE'];
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

It shows the letter as they should be: äöåäö

So the problem is in the `json_encode()` part?
And why does it make the whole row appear as null instead of just making the scandinavian letters to appear as � signs or something?

Comment: What's the table collation set to?

Comment: The data seems to be correct so the problem is `json_encode()` issue. But how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of SET NAMES you should use `$dbh->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to urlencode values or data before creating encoding JSON string.

**EDIT** ALSO: you will need to make sure everything is UTF8-centric, database connection, database tables as well as what you have done for content type...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using utf-8 encoding in your *.php files and in MySQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've said the collation is UTF-8 but try running:

```
$dbh->query('SET NAMES UTF-8');
```

after you create the PDO object, I've found that sometimes it defaults to ISO-8859-1 even though it should use UTF-8.